# PHP Laravel - Getting no Token

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I looked at a tutorial for getting requests with Laravel.
But I do not get the Token. Any ideas?

```
$user->createToken('app')->accessToken;
```

I am Getting

```
"token": {
        "name": "app",
        "abilities": [
            "*"
        ],
```

But it should be like a long cryptic string

[image: This should be the result, but I get the above]

Comment: The first thing that you have to check it first, do the access token generated in table `oauth_personal_access_clients`? If it is not, you must check your database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to create token value

$token=Str::random(64);